# Can a node in a linked list have pointers to itself? C++

Tags: c++, list, linked-list

CS student here. I won't try to hide the fact that this is for homework. 
I know the question is awkward so let me explain,

I'm writing code for an assignment in C++ that uses nodes to simulate a structure of rooms, linked by pointers. Basically its a linked list. I know how to design a linked list so that this would be my room structure. (Just your average stack or queue)

```
 +---+---+---+---+---+  
 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |  
 +---+---+---+---+---+
```

But that structure is one dimensional and only requires links in one/two directions. One for the address of the next node and another for the address of the preceding node. I want to create a 2d structure that looks more like this:

```
    ____+---+  
    ____| R |  
    ____+---+  
    ____| H |  
+---+   +---+   +---+  
| L |. .| H |. .| L |   
+---+   +---+   +---+  
| L |  . . . . .| H |  
+---+  . . . . .+---+  
........... ......^
```

Where L is a lab, H is a hallway, and R is the reactor (we have to define at least 3 different types of room as subclasses of base class Room). And ^ is where you enter from.
The thing I can't straighten out in my design is if I want to be able to move in 4 directions (lets say N, S, E, W), how will I account for there being no room in a direction the user picks?
I am going to assign pointers to all adjacent rooms when a player 'enters' a room, but what should I do about the walls?
Should I assign them to point to the same room the player is in? And then print an error statement? Should I assign them to NULL? Any advice is helpful.

edit @ 7 PST 8.1.15

Wow great responses so far!. @cristophe : I like option 1. Is it possible to instantiate the entire linked list at the start of the program, linking all the rooms together by giving them N, S, E, W pointers to one another, with NULLs for walls?
Assuming I have a base/parent class Room and derived classes Lab, Hall, Reactor that act like nodes, could I have a boolean member variable in these nodes called player that returns true if the player is in the room?

edit @ 4:20 PST 8.4.15

I've coded at least a skeletal version of the structure, and the method worked! Each room is a linked node with 4 pointers for the 4 primary directions. I assign addresses of adjacent rooms to the pointers and the address of the room itself to any direction with a wall. Here is my class definition, I'll post more code when it looks better. All these pointers will hopefully by private in the end, I just haven't got around to writing the accessors yet.

room.h:

#ifndef ROOM_H
 #define ROOM_H

using namespace std;

```
class Room {
    //protected:
    public:
            string roomname;
            int roomtemp;
            int playertemp;
            Room *up;
            Room *down;
            Room *left;
            Room *right;
            Room *player;
            virtual void temp_change(int roomtemp);
            string get_name();
            void set_room(string nameval, Room* up, Room* down, Room* left, Room* right);
            void set_temp();
            void move_player(Room*& current, char action);
```

};

#endif

Comment: Your ASCII art is a bit unclear. You may want to clean that up and change the format so that they are displayed using fixed with font.

Comment: You figure it out yourself. Assigning a NULL pointer is a valid choice. Also, by default, all room pointers can have a default NULL.

Comment: Either would do, but NULL would be slightly easier to work with, and would make more sense.

Comment: @Jackson: I tried to fix your ASCII art, but I don't think it's perfect yet. Could you perhaps clean up the remaining problems (if any)?

Comment: I would use `nullptr` or `0` (`NULL`) because the test is easier and its more intuitive.

Comment: Thx for your help! I cleaned it up some. All rooms can go to any adjacent rooms.

Comment: Manually managing your memory isn't always a good idea. You could try making each

Comment: I'd choose to use null pointer for this. By this you can check the availability of next element by looking at the link itself (without knowing the original element). If you for some reason forget to check the pointer you will in this way get an exception immediately, but if you use pointer to `this` you might end up in an endless loop. Furthermore you could if you use null pointer you still have support for such surreal situations where you end up in the same room if you go in a certain direction (if you'd fancy that).

Comment: Go to MUDBytes and see how it was done "Back In The Day" with Diku Gamma: http://www.mudbytes.net/file-321 (See structs.h and db.)

There were no pointers. No lists. Rooms were *NUMBERED* and stored in *ARRAYS*. Exits to other rooms were one of 6 structures with a description and the number of the other room. And the numbers were *SHORT INT* so as not to use too much valuable RAM.

Answer (score 1):

What you try to implement as a datastructure is more a graph than a linked-list.  And you have many ways to implement this.

First possibility:

- you have a flat linked list or a vector of rooms
- each room has itself a linked list of pointers to adjacent rooms
- problem:  the links shall be related to N, S, W, E
- problem-resolution:  work with pairs (direction+pointer), or use a map instead of a linked list for the adjacent rooms.
- a wall is the absence of the direction in the linked list.

Second possibility:

- you have a flat linked list or a vector of rooms
- each room has itself a vector of 4 pointers (N, S, W, E) to adjacent rooms
- a wall is represented by a `nullptr`

Third possibility:

- you have a flat linked list or a vector of rooms
- each room has 4 pointers to adjacent rooms (like a tree, except they could cylcle).
- a wall is represented by a `nullptr`
- problem:  this is more cumbersome to manipulate than the previous one (i.e. you need a lot of redundant code to iterate through the 4 directions)

Fourth possibility:

- you have a vector of N rooms
- you have a matrix of N x N  adjacency relation between rooms
- the matrix value for room i and room j tells which direction you have to take to go from i to j,  or a neutral value indicating that the rooms are not connected

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that yes it can, by combining a normal list with the room info (which includes pointers to other nodes).

You solve your problem by actually combining two structures: one to keep track of all the rooms (a regular list), and one to keep track of room data such as what rooms are adjacent. You CAN combine these into one struct:

```
struct room_list_element {
    // Use these for regular linked list stuff
    room_list_node *prev = nullptr;
    room_list_node *next = nullptr;

    // Use this for traversing the structure as 2 dimensions
    room_list_node *N = nullptr;
    room_list_node *E = nullptr;
    room_list_node *S = nullptr;
    room_list_node *W = nullptr;
    std::string room_name;
}
```

Then you could make a linked list of rooms as normal, then find "Bridge" and connect its "S" pointer to "Engineering," then find "Engineering" and connect its "N" pointer to "Bridge," etc. Walls are represented by nullptr's.

You can then access the list both by prev/next, and by N/E/S/W. You would use prev/next for searching for a room, allocating/deleting data, etc., and N/E/S/W to move a player pointer.

You're basically combining two different data structures in a messy kludge, though. It works, but it's *poor design*! When you want to add more things to rooms, you have to add them to the your list nodes. This is very un-OO. So why not do it right?

I will use a simple example of a map that has three rooms: Bridge, which is north of the second room, Engineering. Engineering has Bridge to the north and Guns to the East.

```
struct Room {
    Room *N = nullptr;
    Room *S = nullptr;
    Room *E = nullptr;
    Room *W = nullptr;
    // whatever other information you want about rooms here
    std::string Name; // etc. etc.
};

// ... later on,
std::list<Room *> rooms;
Room new_room;

new_room = new Room;
new_room->name = "Bridge";
rooms.push_back(new_room); // Put it into the list
new_room = new Room;
new_room->name = "Engineering";
rooms.push_back(new_room); // Put it into the list again
new_room = new Room;
new_room->name = "Guns";
rooms.push_back(new_room); // Put it into the list again

// Connect them up. This is where it gets super-kludgy.
auto& room_to_connect_1 = rooms.begin();
auto& room_to_connect_2 = rooms.begin()++;
auto& room_to_connect_3 = (rooms.begin()++)++;

room_to_connect_1->S = room_to_connect_2; // Bridge->S = Engineering
room_to_connect_2->N = room_to_connect_1; // Engineering-> N = Bridge

room_to_connect_2->E = room_to_connect_3; // Engineering->E = Guns
room_to_connect_3->W = room_to_connect_2; // Guns->W = Engineering

Room player_room = room_to_connect_2; // Player starts in engineering
```

All we're doing here is moving the extra data out of the list structure. It is still a list of rooms that we can make into a 2D map, plus we get to use std::list, which is better than rolling our own.

In terms of design though, this still falls short on many levels. First, memory leaks galore. Second, finding and connecting rooms is a pain! 
Let's do it a much better way, which probably isn't acceptable for homework.

Here is a demonstration program with a simple map that has a Bridge and Engineering located to the south of that.

```
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

// This structure holds our room info
struct Room {
    Room *N = nullptr;
    Room *S = nullptr;
    Room *E = nullptr;
    Room *W = nullptr;
    // whatever other information you want about rooms here
    std::string Name; // etc. etc.

    Room(std::string room_name) : Name(room_name) { } // sets Name to name
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // We make a list here to handle deleting rooms, and a map to to index rooms by name.
    // Because we use unique_ptr in the vector, it will handle deleting the objects when the vector is freed!
    std::list<std::unique_ptr<Room>> room_destroyer; // *This is actually the 2-dimensional linked list you wanted to make earlier,* just with better design. You can traverse it with prev/next and each element has pointers to other elements.
    std::map<std::string, Room *> room_map; 

    // This will hold track of where the player is for us. Could be part of a "player" object or whatever.
    Room *player_room = nullptr;

    // Let's make two rooms.
    std::unique_ptr<Room> new_room;

    // First the bridge
    new_room = std::make_unique<Room>("Bridge");
    room_map.emplace(new_room->Name, new_room.get());
    room_destroyer.push_back(std::move(new_room)); // Notice we do this last, because our "new_room" pointer will no longer point to or own anything. We use std::move() to "transfer ownership" to the pointer that the list creates when we push_back.

    new_room = std::make_unique<Room>("Engineering");
    room_map.emplace(new_room->Name, new_room.get());
    room_destroyer.push_back(std::move(new_room)); // Notice again that we do this last, because our "new_room" pointer will no longer point to or own anything

    // Now let's connect it so that the bridge is north of engineering and vice-versa
    auto& room_to_connect_1 = room_map.find("Bridge"); // auto& takes care of making an iterator for us without messy syntax.
    // Remember, std::maps return iterators where ->first is the key (i.e. name), and -> second is the value (a pointer to the room)
    auto& room_to_connect_2 = room_map.find("Engineering");
    if ((room_to_connect_1 == room_map.end()) || 
        (room_to_connect_2 == room_map.end()) ) {
        // We can't find one of the rooms? Ouch!
    }
    else {
        room_to_connect_1->second->S = room_to_connect_2->second; // Bridge's S = Engineering
        room_to_connect_2->second->N = room_to_connect_1->second; // Engineering's N = Bridge
    }

    // Now that we've done all that, let's put the player in engineering and print where we are.
    player_room = room_map.find("Engineering")->second; // find() returns an iterator. Map iterators return ->first as the key, and ->second as the value (the pointer to the room)
    if (player_room == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "Engineering not found while trying to put the player there! Why!?" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    std::cout << "The player is in the " << player_room->Name << std::endl;

    // Let's try moving north. Remember, we set ourselves to be in Engineering, which has an "N" link to the Bridge
    std::cout << "Player tries to move north." << std::endl;
    if (nullptr != player_room->N) {
        player_room = player_room->N;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "There is no room to the north!" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "The player is in the " << player_room->Name << std::endl;

    // Let's try moving east.
    std::cout << "Player tries to move east." << std::endl;
    if (nullptr != player_room->E) {
        player_room = player_room->E;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "There is no room to the east!" << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "The Player is in the " << player_room->Name << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::endl << "Press enter to exit" << std::endl;
    getc(stdin);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
The player is in the Engineering.
Player tries to move north.
The player in the Bridge
Player tries to move east.
There is no room to the east!
The player is in the Bridge

Press enter to exit
```

Answer (score 0):

Maintaining some kind of collection (array or vector) of your room information is of course a must.

It's really a design choice as to whether you want each room object to be responsible for knowing the connections it shares with other rooms, or if that information is separate from the room data.

An alternative to pointers between rooms would be a matrix `a` (for n rooms, n * n) with `a[x][y]` representing some information about the state of the connection between the two rooms. It could be simple boolean (yes there is a route, no there isn't) information, or more complex (0 - no connection, 1 - locked connection... etc). This would enable more complexity in your 'level map', but might be fiddlier to code, and if you wanted to have defined movement directions, your time complexity for finding the response to a given direction of motion would scale with n (have to check the entire row in the matrix in the worst case, average case about half), whereas a set of four straight pointers would give constant time complexity. Worth considering.

If you go down the route of each room knowing about its connections, using null pointers to represent walls is a valid choice.
It's worth bearing in mind from a level-design point of view that it could be fun to permit self-references - think Neo in the self-repeating subway! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lEWIn0p6OUM

Comment: The last point I mentioned would mean you'd have to distinguish between no connection (probably a null), a self-referencing connection (pointer to this room object) and a bog-standard external connection (pointer to another room.) If you wanted to encode factors like the state of the connection like I mentioned, you could also have a series of flag fields in each room, one for each direction, representing the status of that connection (perhaps int fields). This sounds like a case where experimenting and thinking about design choices will pay off. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try graph data structure to solve this. 
Use 4 different values for 4 directions so that your goal is achieved.